# Plots not printed over multiple pages

Tags: r, shiny

I have developed app to allow users to download all the plots in the app to PDF file. The code somewhat works, but not as I expected.

The number of plots are dynamic (as it depends on the data). I have use marrangeGrob function but all my plots are still on the same page, instead of seeing one on each page

Is there a setting I have missed? Also, I would like to adjust the height and the width for each chart as well (make the width shorter and the height longer), is there an option to do so?

Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinydashboard)

### UI & Module -------------------
plotUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  plotOutput(ns("myplot"))
}

plotServer <- function(id,groups) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      filtered.data <- reactive(iris %>% filter(Species == groups))

      create_graph <- reactive(filtered.data() %>% ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +geom_col())
  
      output$myplot <- renderPlot(create_graph())  
      
      return(list(graph = create_graph))
    }  
  )    
}


### UI part -----------------------
ui <- dashboardPage(
  title="test",
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(downloadButton('download')),
  dashboardBody(uiOutput('tablist'))
)

### Server part ----------------------------
server = function(input, output) { 
  groups <- reactive(unique(iris$Species))
  ntabs <- reactive(length(groups()))

  allplots <- reactiveVal()
  
  observeEvent(ntabs(),{
    plot <- lapply(1:ntabs(), function (i) {
      plotServer(paste0("plot",i),groups()[i])
    })
    allplots(plot)
  })  
  
  output$tablist = renderUI({
    addtabs <- lapply(1:ntabs(),function (i) {
      tabPanel(
        groups()[i],
        plotUI(paste0("plot",i)),
      )
    })
    do.call(tabsetPanel, addtabs)
  })
  
  output$download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste0("plots-", Sys.Date(), ".pdf")
    }, content = function(file) {
      plot.list <- allplots()
      ggsave(file,marrangeGrob(lapply(plot.list, function(x) x$graph()),
                               ncol = 1, nrow = length(plot.list)))
      
    }
  )
}

### Running part ----------------------------
shinyApp(ui, server,enableBookmarking = "server")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we specify `ncol = 1` and `nrow = 1`, every plot goes in a separate page because the layout gets "recycled".

```
  output$download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste0("plots-", Sys.Date(), ".pdf")
    }, content = function(file) {
      plot.list <- allplots()
      ggsave(file, marrangeGrob(
        grobs = plot.list |> lapply(\(x) x$graph()),
        ncol  = 1,
        nrow  = 1
      ))
    }
  )
```